# Magento contact form not displaying

Tags: blocks, contact-us

I have a CMS page Contact Us, which has the following

> {{block type=’core/template’ name=’contactForm’ template=’contacts/form.phtml’}}

However on the Contact Us page the block isn't being loaded, instead I've got an empty `<p></p>` any idea's on what might cause this, I have a custom theme but the contact form isn't being overridden by that theme.

Comment: check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058917/add-contact-form-to-static-block-in-magento

Comment: correct your syntex {{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the looks of it, it might be as simple as the quotations that you have in your declaration.  If you copied and pasted they may be wrong and you may just need to erase and enter them again.  It has happened to me before.  Also if that isn't the case check error logs to see if anything is missing and post them back if you can.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why do you want to add the contact form in a cms page and not use the default contacts page.
Even if you manage to make the contact form appear you won't be able to send messages through it.
This happens because the action of the form is `<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>`. In your case this will be empty and you will submit the form to the CMS page in which you added the form. And the page does not handle the post.
In the default contacts page the action for the form is set in the controller (I don't know why is this, seams like a bad decision from Magento):
`Mage_Contacts_IndexController::indexAction()`

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
    ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
....
```

My recommendation is to stick to the default contact page and if you need something custom in the form just copy the `form.phtml` file to your theme and change it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```